# Using a Fourier series to solve a BVP...

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

How would I go about solving questions 1a and 3b?

- 1.(a): $-\dfrac{d^2u}{dx^2}=1$, $u(0)=u(1)=0$;
- 3.(c): $-\dfrac{d^2u}{dx^2}+2u=1$, $u(0)=u(1)=0$;

[image: scan of book page]

For (1a) do we assume a solution of the form $u(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} u_ne^{inx}$ and substitute this into the differential equation to get $u_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$?How would we apply the boundary condition?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Two things.  (1), you should edit your post not to use the triple "???" question marks.  That could be perceived as rude or sounding exasperated, which isn't the desired tone for this community.

(2) As for your actual question 1a, consider using a series of sines and cosines, rather than exponential functions.  You'll be pleasantly surprised to find that the cosines all get zero coefficients, leaving you to investigate the coefficients of the sine series.

Comment: How would you find the Fourier series of the RHS as well as the boundary conditions?

Comment: What do they mean with "shifting the data"? Are you allowed to shift $u$ to $v+\frac12x(1-x)$, so that $v''=0$?

Answer (score 1):

For (a) assume a solution of the form $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \sin(n\pi x)$.

For (b) assume a solution of the same form.